# What is a word that refers to the state of appearing only as a head without a body, as in the case of an apparition or God

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that refers to the state of appearing as only a head without a body, as in the case of an apparition or god.  I think the word would be used in a sentence something like this:  "The goddess Athena appeared [blank] to him and foretold his future."

I know I have run into the word in use before and had to look it up. But I have forgotten what the word is. I am pretty sure that I found the word on [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/). To my best recollection, it is a foreign-sounding word, most likely Latin[ish].

Comment: It's a horseless headman.

Comment: A talking head?

Comment: No. It is not _talking head_ or _horseless headman_.

Comment: This isn't some mash-up between the idea of godhead and the word 'incarnate' is it?

Comment: BruiserTom, @HotLicks wasn't being serious: https://youtu.be/-343UI_MNK8

Comment: "**Dormammu**, I've come to bargain" https://youtu.be/s3lA6abQprM

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for ***disembodied***

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/disembodied)

> seeming to not have a body or not to be connected to a body

In the sense you want it,

> The goddess Athena's ***disembodied head*** appeared to him and foretold his future.

or a little more subtly:

> ***Disembodied***, the goddess Athena appeared to him and foretold his future.

The prefix ***dis-*** has a Latin origin, ***em-*** is Middle English via Norman French *en-*, and ***body*** is good old Anglo-Saxon.

If you're looking for a pithy Latin phrase, you could try ***tantum in capite***, which simply means "only a head".

Comment: I can't for the life of me understand why Cambridge Dictionary has a dumbed-down version of the definition as its "US English" definition.

Comment: Thanks. But disembodied is not the word I am thinking of. I am sure I will know the word when I see it. I believe the word I am searching for means appearing as a head with no body. I think your last example could refer to a spectral image of a complete body.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you're looking for, but here's a *bust* of Athena.

[image: Bust of Athena]

A Latin word that comes to mind is *effigy*.

Also, *numen*.

Comment: I don't know Latin, but in English *effigy* and *numen* don't imply a head without a body.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Raw Head component of "raw head and bloody bones" is what you're looking for.  The  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/158702?rskey=vS3Hbp&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) defines it as follows, with citations from 1564:

1. Frequently in form Raw-head. A bugbear or bogeyman, typically imagined as having a head in the form of a skull, or one whose flesh has been stripped of its skin, invoked to frighten children. Also occasionally: a skull. Frequently used in conjunction with bloody-bones (see Bloody Bones n.). Cf. raw-flesh n., raw neck n.

It's also discussed in the Wiki article on  [Bloody Bones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloody_Bones)  .

Comment: The OP didn't mention the head being stripped of flesh or bloody...

Comment: I agree -- I posted it as a remote possibility, more head-specific than _manifestation_ or _apparition_.  The two specific "heads alone" apparitions I can think of are the Three Heads in a Well, and Friar Bacon's Brazen Head.

Answer (score 0):

*incorporeal* is how i would try to describe any supposed mind that hasn't yet been disproven to exist in some untestable, unknowable and nonsensical place referred to as 'outside space and time.' i know there's an absence of a 'head' by definition, but...

Comment: This isn't one of those cases where the premise of a question is wrong and an answer could explain why and then go in a different direction. The OP's comment under that other answer again makes it very clear they only want a term for a head with no body. They don't want to widen the scope. If they're not satisfied with *disembodied* they're certainly not going to accept *incorporeal*, even though *incorporeal* is a pretty cool word in a general sense.